# Data prints out multiple times instead of once

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cheerio

I made a web scraping app in `node.js` that takes `p.title` and `p.artist` from the HTML of the site then stores each of the two elements in two separate arrays like this:

```
res.on('data', function(html){
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var commonTitles = [];
  var commonArtists = [];

  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(0)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(1)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(2)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(3)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(4)));

  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(0)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(1)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(2)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(3)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(4)));

  console.log(
    'The 5 most recently played titles: \n' +
    commonTitles[0] + ' / ' + commonArtists[0] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[1] + ' / ' + commonArtists[1] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[2] + ' / ' + commonArtists[2] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[3] + ' / ' + commonArtists[3] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[4] + ' / ' + commonArtists[4]
  );
});
```

I want to list all the 5 most recently played song titles with their artists from a site and print them out with the help of `console.log`. I'm expecting to get this as my output in command prompt:

```
The 5 most recently played titles:
I Make It Rain (Original Trap Mix) / Jimithegenius
More Pragmatic (Original Version) / Jahnauasca
Kiss The Devil (Just A Gent Remix) / Bel Hair
Check (Levitate Remix) / Meek Mill
Party Right (Charlie Traplin Trap Mix) / Lethal Bizzle feat. Ruby Goe
```

The playlist updates once in a while so this is just an example.
Instead of printing them out like that it prints them out with additional arguements without the arrays, as if the `console.log` has been put into a strange loop like this:

```
The 5 most recently played titles:
/
/
/
/
/
The 5 most recently played titles:
/
/
/
/
/
The 5 most recently played titles:
I Make It Rain (Original Trap Mix) / Jimithegenius
More Pragmatic (Original Version) / Jahnauasca
Kiss The Devil (Just A Gent Remix) / Bel Hair
Check (Levitate Remix) / Meek Mill
Party Right (Charlie Traplin Trap Mix) / Lethal Bizzle feat. Ruby Goe
The 5 most recently played titles:
/
/
/
/
/
The 5 most recently played titles:
/
/
/
/
/
```

Why does it print out additional data?
If the `console.log` would've been in a loop, then all of the additional output wouldn't be empty, all of them would contain data from the arrays. I even tried creating the arrays outside of `res.on` as global arrays, but then it prints the titles and artists as `undefined`. How do I get rid of these unwanted lines?

Thanks in advance,
**Tim_W8**

Comment: "res.on" is called 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to listen in both `data` and `end` to make this work.

`data` is called each time a chunk of data arrives.

`end` is called all all data arrive.

```
var html = '';
res.on('data', function(chunk){
   html+=chunk;
});

res.on('end',function(){

  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var commonTitles = [];
  var commonArtists = [];

  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(0)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(1)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(2)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(3)));
  commonTitles.push($.text($('p.title').eq(4)));

  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(0)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(1)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(2)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(3)));
  commonArtists.push($.text($('p.artist').eq(4)));

  console.log(
    'The 5 most recently played titles: \n' +
    commonTitles[0] + ' / ' + commonArtists[0] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[1] + ' / ' + commonArtists[1] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[2] + ' / ' + commonArtists[2] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[3] + ' / ' + commonArtists[3] + '\n' +
    commonTitles[4] + ' / ' + commonArtists[4]
  );
})
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much!